# libavformat/libavfilter transcoded audio is choppy

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libavformat

I am attempting to transcode an mp4 file into a standard format. The video seems ok but the audio is choppy (and out of sync with the video).

My test input file has the following properties:

```
Stream #0:1(eng), 0, 1/48000: Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, 129 kb/s (default)
```

and I'm outputing to:

```
Stream #0:1, 0, 1/44100: Audio: aac (libfaac) (Main), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
```

When I construct the audio filter graph I get the following debug output:

```
[in @ 0x103954380] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/48000'
[in @ 0x103954380] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '48000'
[in @ 0x103954380] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 'fltp'
[in @ 0x103954380] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x3'
[in @ 0x103954380] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[format @ 0x10390b3e0] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 's16'
[format @ 0x10390b3e0] Setting 'sample_rates' to value '44100'
[format @ 0x10390b3e0] Setting 'channel_layouts' to value '0x3'
[format @ 0x10390b3e0] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted resampler 0' between the filter 'in' and the filter 'format'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x101f21b80] query_formats: 3 queried, 3 merged, 3 already done, 0 delayed
[auto-inserted resampler 0 @ 0x103952bc0] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:fltp r:48000Hz -> ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:s16 r:44100Hz
```

This looks correct to me but I'm getting a lot of the following messages when I process the file...

```
[libfaac @ 0x102063a00] Trying to remove 80 more samples than there are in the queue
```

...and the audio is choppy. Also I'm seeing that the sample format is the same as the original file (from ffprobe):

```
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (Main) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
```

i.e. it hasn't done the conversion from AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT to AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16.

I'm wondering if the bitrate is the cause of the problem but I can't see any way to transform the input bitrate to the output bitrate. Any thoughts?